# Lightning Datatable with custom editTemplate will not show editValue in default template prior to save submission

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable

Between [this salesforce guidance](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.data_table_custom_types_editable_example) and inspiration from [this popular playground lwc](https://live.playg.app/play/picklist-in-lightning-datatable) I've arrived at my near working solution.

This screenshot kinda says it all. When I was on row 1, I already clicked the pencil icon and selected an option from my lightning-combobox.. and notice the yellow highlight: **good**, however when the `editTemplate` pop-up exited, the default `template` remains *blank*: **bad**

Before taking the screenshot, I clicked the pencil icon on row 2 so you could see again what the `editTemplate` looks like in action:

[image: lightning-datatable with custom dropdown]

The field is correctly highlighted in yellow by the lighting-datatable component - it properly recognizes my interaction with the custom `editTemplate` that I designed. And if I save my data, the `draftValues` have been properly updated so the correct changed-data will be submitted. But, why can't I get the editValue to populate back to the default non-interactive `template`

[image: screenshot of rossDataTable.js]

> picklist-template-edit.html  (works just like I want)

```html
<template>
    <c-ross-datatable-picklist 
        data-inputable="true"
        fieldname={columnLabel} 
        value={editedValue}
        placeholder={typeAttributes.placeholder} 
        options={typeAttributes.options} 
        context={typeAttributes.context}>
    </c-ross-datatable-picklist>
</template>
```

> picklist-template.html  (this is my conundrum. how to make it show edited value?)

```html
<template>
    <p>{typeAttributes.value}</p>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

My picklist-template.html should be like this:

```html
<template>
    <p>{value}</p>
</template>
```